# How to add ssh kex algorithms to cisco sg350

Tags: cisco-sg300, cisco-small-business

This is in reference to question:

[Scan sg350-28 with Nessus Credentialed checks](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/77911/scan-sg350-28-with-nessus-credentialed-checks)

I have been working on this for the past couple weeks and think I have figured out what the issue is:

```
[2022-02-15 21:11:11] [session 1] try_ssh_kb_settings_login: Opening a connection to port 22 to test 'none' authentication...
[2022-02-15 21:11:11] [session 1] session.open_connection: Connecting to port 22.
[2022-02-15 21:11:11] [session 1] session.open_connection: Socket opened on port 22.
[2022-02-15 21:11:11] [session 1] ssh_client_state.set: ** Entering STATE SOC_OPENED **
[2022-02-15 21:11:11] [session 1] session.open_connection: Received server version SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.3p1.RL
[2022-02-15 21:11:11] [session 1] session.sshsend: Outgoing Unencrypted packet:

0x00:  53 53 48 2D 32 2E 30 2D 4F 70 65 6E 53 53 48 5F    SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_
0x10:  35 2E 30 0A                                        5.0.            
[2022-02-15 21:11:11] [session 1] try_ssh_kb_settings_login: Successfully opened a connection on port 22.
[2022-02-15 21:11:11] [session 1] session.complete_kex: KEX is not yet complete. Attempting to complete KEX before continuing.
[2022-02-15 21:11:58] [session 1] session.sshrecv: Incoming Unencrypted packet:
0x00:  00 00 00 34 07 01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 1F 69 64    ...4..........id
0x10:  6C 65 20 63 6F 6E 6E 65 63 74 69 6F 6E 20 74 69    le connection ti
0x20:  6D 65 6F 75 74 20 65 78 70 69 72 65 64 00 00 00    meout expired...
0x30:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                            ........        
[2022-02-15 21:11:58] [session 1] session.sshrecv_until: Handling packet.type: 1 [PROTO_SSH_MSG_DISCONNECT]
```

That session timeout is occurring because the hand shake is not going through correctly and is timing out.

Doing a lot of google fu I was looking over how to add or even check what algorithm are enable on the switch

From the verbose output of ssh I cannot really tell what is missing.

This is from the server were nessus is installed

```
[root@localhost ~]# ssh -vv aftest@192.168.1.254
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "192.168.1.254" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.254 [192.168.1.254] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.3p1.RL
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.3p1.RL pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.254:22 as 'aftest'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1 need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1 need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<8192<8192) sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: bits set: 1004/2048
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:gKvy1VIaUuuof58/pXPIki3lG5uhIxLBewVAL9oWS0s
debug1: Host '192.168.1.254' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 1054/2048
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password
debug1: Next authentication method: password

aftest@192.168.1.254's password:

debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 192.168.1.254 ([192.168.1.254]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 2097152 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0




switch778de9>
```

I am not sure how to get the same output from nessus, nor am I sure why I can ssh from the server and not the nessus application.

The cisco sg350 switches have a stripped down IOS version and a lot of the command I see online are not available

For instance:

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/sec_usr_ssh/configuration/xe-16-10/sec-usr-ssh-xe-16-10-book/sec-secure-shell-algorithm-ccc.html

```
Device# configure terminal
Device# ip ssh {server | client } algorithm mac {hmac-sha1 | hmac-sha1-96 }
```

This is the output from the Cisco sg350 switch

```
switch778de9#configure
switch778de9(config)#ip
  access-list          This command creates an ACL, which perform
                       classification on layer 3 fields and enters ip-access
                       configuration mode.
  arp                  ARP configuration commands
  default-gateway      Specify default gateway
  dhcp                 IP DHCP client commands
  domain               IP Domain Naming System
  helper-address       Specify a destination address for UDP broadcasts
  host                 To define static host name-to-address mapping in the
                       host cache
  http                 Specify the HTTP server configuration
  https                HTTPS server configuration
  igmp                 IGMP interface commands
  igmp-proxy           IGMP proxy configurations
  multicast-routing    To enable IP multicast routing
  name-server          To set the available name servers, use the ip
                       name-server global configuration command.
  route                Establish static routes
  routing              Enable IP routing
  source-guard         IP source-guard configuration
  ssh                  Global Secure Shell protocol configuration subcommands
  ssh-client           secure shell client.
  telnet               Telnet server configuration
switch778de9(config)#ip ssh
  password-auth        To enable password authentication for incoming SSH
                       sessions
  port                 Specify the port to be used by the SSH server.  To use
                       the default port, use the no form of this command.
  pubkey-auth          To enable public key authentication for incoming SSH
  server               Enable the device to be configured from SSH.  Use the
                       no form of this command to disable this function.
switch778de9(config)#ip ssh server
   <CR>
switch778de9(config)#ip ssh server
```

Is there anything else I can check?

Comment: "_The cisco sg350 switches have a stripped down IOS version_" No, the SG devices do not use IOS, and you need to use the references for the SG switches, e.g. https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/csbms/350xg/cli_guide/CLI_Tesla_SG350X_SG350XG_2_2_5.pdf

Comment: I don't know how to change it on the switch, but it's always going to be the limiting factor. The scanner needs to be told to use settings the switch supports. (kex, digest, etc.) Where one would set those for nessus, I can't say. From what I've seen, it should be telling you what was tried but did not work.

Comment: @Ricky I think is was saying it was using Kex, not sure if that is right or not

Comment: The error message should say what Key EXchange mechanisms it tried.

Answer (score 1):

Key exchange mechanisms failing is usually an indication of incomplete key generation. The switch might not have local keys yet. Check whether that's the case:

```
show crypto key
```

If it's missing try creating public/private key pairs by running

```
crypto key generate rsa
crypto key generate dsa
```

(DSA should be preferred but some application may require RSA.)

Also, your Nessus server might have the same problem. You should check the installation guide to see if you've missed that part.

Comment: Sorry made no difference